# Is it possible to setup bean parameters with enums or named constants?

Tags: java, xml, spring, enums, instantiation

For example I have

```
public enum ID { CODEC1, CODEC2 }
```

and a bean

```
public class Bean {
   private ID id;
   public ID getId() { return id; }
   public void setId(ID value) { this.id = value; }
}
```

Is it possible to use symbolic names in Spring config somehow? For instance

```
<bean id="bean" class="Bean">
   <parameter name="id" value="CODEC1"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Spring 3.1, the code that you wrote should work. When using a previous version, try defining `valueOf` of the enum as factory method:

```
<bean id="CODEC1" class="ID" factory-method="valueOf">
     <constructor-arg>   
         <value>CODEC1</value>
     </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

and

```
<parameter name="id" value-ref="CODEC1"/>
```

Comment: Do you mean that Spring 3+ will see that field type is `enum` and will scan that `enum` class automatically for string representations??? That's great!

Answer (score 1):

Give the following SpEL a try:

```
<property name="id" value="#{T(my.package.ID).valueOf('CODEC1')}"/>
```